# Python Tkinter listbox color individual word

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, listbox, customtkinter

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348454) I know how to color individual items in a `listbox`. However, is it possible to color individual words/characters inside the item of a Tkinter `listbox`?

If yes, how to achieve that?

If no, is there a way to work around the limitations, such as transforming a Tkinter TextBox into a ListBox (so you can click on individual lines), while still being able to color anything and everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change individual words in a `Listbox` widget. Your only choices are to use a `Text` widget or a `Canvas` widget, with the `Text` widget by far being the easiest.

You can certainly use the `Text` widget as the basis for replicating the features of the `Listbox`. You'll have to add your own bindings for selecting whole lines, and add your own methods and virtual events to emulate the `Listbox`.